# How to turn off application minimization and keep it running in backgroud

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, screen-sharing

How to turn off application minimization. I have an application that must run in the background (logitech screen share, never mind) but it deactivates when it is minimized and it breaks my other scripts in chrome/firefox.I can't share this application via chrome screen share / firefox when someone minimizes this soft

Answer (score 0):

To keep a specific window always as bottom-most in the display order (Z-order),
you may use the free tool
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will move the Calculator window to background
whenever it appears, checking every 100 milliseconds:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Persistent

SetTimer, CheckBottom, 100
CheckBottom:
IfWinExist, Calculator
  WinSet, Bottom
return
```

If the `WinSet` command does not work for your application, another variant
sets the window to be a direct child of the desktop:

```
DllCall("SetParent", UInt, WinExist() , UInt, WinExist("Program Manager"))
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

See also the article
[[How To] Set a GUI to be " Always at Bottom"](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/80573-how-to-set-a-gui-to-be-always-at-bottom/).